# Does not exist in current context Registration form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, scope

Hey guys still busy with the registration form article I found, I followed the guys steps and inserted the code he posted but I seem to get the error "does not exist in current context" Am I doing something wrong or is his code a problem?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rohatash/simple-user-login-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class StudentLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strcon = "Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=Password$2;database=master";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("VC-Temps", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("StudCode", TextBox3.Text);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("Password", TextBox4.Text);
    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("FirstName", TextBox5.Text);
    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("LastName", TextBox6.Text);
    SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("Telephone", TextBox7.Text);
    SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("Course", TextBox8.Text);
    SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("Availability", DropDownList1.Text);
    SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("JobSkill", DropDownList2.Text);
    SqlParameter p9 = new SqlParameter("Experience", DropDownList3.Text);
    com.Parameters.Add(p1);
    com.Parameters.Add(p2);
    com.Parameters.Add(p3);
    com.Parameters.Add(p4);
    com.Parameters.Add(p5);
    com.Parameters.Add(p6);
    com.Parameters.Add(p7);
    com.Parameters.Add(p8);
    com.Parameters.Add(p9);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
}
```

Error is : Error    3   The name 'CommandType' does not exist in the current context    C:\Website\StudentLogin.aspx.cs 21  27  C:\Website\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide full namespace or add `using System.Data.SqlClient`.

Right click on `CommandType` and choose an item from `Resolve` menu..

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> while the carret is on the problematic word.

EDIT: Reference to `System.Data` is needed, check this first.

Comment: +1, and `CommandType` is in the `System.Data.CommandType` namespace, which will appear in the Resolve menu.

Comment: make sure you are opening the connection inside a method. me stupid

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had a semicolon in the using statement. Took me a while to see it.

```
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)); <=no no
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved mine by explicitly including the following as well as `using System.Data.SqlClient`:

```
using System.Data;
```

Turns out `using System.Data.SqlClient` wasn't enough.